# Scala: arguments contravariant and return types are covariant why?

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

In the FP in Scala course, Martin mentions, the arguments are "contravariant" while the return types are "covariant". I don't think I understood that completely - can someone help with this one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assume `Bonobo` extends `Animal` and you have a function `foo` of type `Animal => Bonobo`. In some other place you have a variable `bar` of type `Bonobo => Animal`. Should you be allowed to assign `foo` to `bar`? Sure:

- `foo` expects just an animal as argument (which is "too wide" or "too general" compared to the expected argument type `Bonobo` of `bar`, hence contravariant), but it has no problem processing a bonobo.
- you get a bonobo back from `foo` (which is "too narrow" or "too special" compared to the expected return type `Animal` of `bar`, hence covariant), but this is fine, as the caller of `bar` expects to deal with all kinds of animals

But you can't turn the example around, you can't assign a `Bonobo => Animal` function where an `Animal => Bonobo` function is expected, as the argument doesn't fit (it might get an animal that isn't a bonobo), and the return type is wrong either (you need a bonobo back, but get an animal, which could be something different).

This is true for all function-like things (e.g. methods): It doesn't matter if argument types are more general and return types are be more special than expected. "Contravariant" and "covariant" is just fancy terminology for this simple fact.

Comment: +1, this finally made it click for me. Some glitch in my mind that took some time to ditch was: when you have a function that expects a `Bonobo`, but you pass in an `Animal`, don't you then risk allowing passing in animals that are incompatible? But this is a brainfart. When you assign `foo` to `bar`, the type of `bar` remains `Bonobo -> Animal`, so only bonobos will be allowed in the function. And indeed, the `foo` function which then handles that bonobo is perfectly able to, since it handles animals and a bonobo is one.