# Functions are contravariant in their argument types and co-variant in their return types

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360259/scala-arguments-contravariant-and-return-types-are-covariant-why) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321921/isnt-the-argument-type-co-not-contra-variant) answers before posting this question, but I am still a bit unclear in my understanding of this topic as explained below:

I understand what covariant and contravariant independently mean.

If I have classes as below:

```
class Car {}
class SportsCar extends Car {}
class Ferrari extends SportsCar {}
```

And:

```
object covar extends App {

    // Test 1: Works as expected

    def test1( arg: SportsCar => SportsCar ) = {
        new SportsCar
    }

    def foo1(arg: Car): Ferrari = { new Ferrari }
    def foo2(arg: SportsCar): Car = { new Ferrari }
    def foo3(arg: Ferrari): Ferrari = { new Ferrari }

    test1(foo1) // compiles
    test1(foo2) // Fails due to wrong return type - violates return type is covariant
    test1(foo3) // Fails due to wrong parameter type - violates param type is contravariant

    // Test 2: Confused - why can I call test2 succesfully with ferrari 
    // as the parameter, and unsuccesfully with a car as the parameter?

    def test2(arg: SportsCar): SportsCar = {
        new Ferrari
    }

    val car = new Car()
    val sportsCar = new SportsCar()
    val ferrari = new Ferrari()

    val f1 = test2(ferrari)  // compiles - why?
    val f2 = test2(car)      // fails - why?

}
```

As mentioned above, in the Test 2, why can I call test2 succesfully with ferrari as the parameter, and unsuccesfully with a car as the parameter?

Does the statement **Functions are contravariant in their argument types and co-variant in their return types** only apply to functions which are passed as arguments? I guess I am not making appropriate distinction between the statement and the 2 tests that I wrote.

Comment: The `test2` isn't that much related to `test1`. First one examines subtyping relation of `function`s themselves and second one subtyping of plain old classes.

Comment: By making your class hierarchy you are saying that every `Ferrari` IS-A `SportsCar`, and it should be treated that way. That's why you can pass a specific class when a base class is espected, but not the other way around, like in last line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because you're mixing *subtyping* with *co/contravariance.*

In your first example you expect a `Function1[-T, +R]`. In that case, the rules of co/contravariance apply to the *function type*. In your second example, you follow simple subtyping rules.

In `test1`, where you pass in `foo1` which is `Car => Ferrari` everything works because `foo1` expects a `Car`, but gets a `SportsCar`, which is a `Car`. Any method that requires a `Car` can deal with a subtype because of the subtyping nature. But these rules don't work when we talk about subtyping alone.

If we expand `test1` with `foo1` with the actual types, perhaps it'll be clearer:

#### foo1:

- Argument type:

  - Expectation: `Car`
  - Actual: `SportsCar`
- Return type:

  - Expectation: `SportsCar`
  - Actual: `Ferrari`

Everything lines up well.

In `test2` the rules change. If I expect a `SportsCar` you pass in *any car*, then I can no longer depend on the input being a sports car and everything breaks, but if you pass in a ferrari which is actually a sports car, everything is fine.

Again, let's line up the types:

#### test2:

- First case:

  - Argument type:

    - Expectation: `SportsCar`
    - Actual: `Ferrari` (subtype)
  - Result: everyone is happy
- Second case:

  - Argument type:

    - Expectation: `SportsCar`
    - Actual: `Car`
  - Result: Error. We're not sure car is an actual sports car.